# SIGSEGV in java process in docker container

Tags: java, segmentation-fault

I am getting SIGSEGV error from my jvm process and not able to find out what's causing it. Here's the brief error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007efe4920cac6, pid=15, tid=0x00007efdc6cfe700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_141-b32) (build 1.8.0_141-b32)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.141-b32 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# J 471 C2 java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/AbstractStringBuilder; (50 bytes) @ 0x00007efe4920cac6 [0x00007efe4920c840+0x286]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /opt/tango/core or core.15
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000036c6800):  JavaThread "http://172.18.0.5:8002/netty-client-7" daemon [_thread_in_Java, id=56, stack(0x00007efdc6bfe000,0x00007efdc6cff000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 0 (SI_USER)
```

The full error can be accessed at https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MgCV8-IHi-1e4sizAlOlgSQdKPuye_kh-2nSlsmh5UU/edit?usp=drivesdk

Could you please help?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/crashes.html

Comment: Thanks Amir..I did go through the article.. I want to confirm here whether this error is due to my application code or some other reason..

Answer (score 1):

> siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 0 (SI_USER)

This means a `kill()` was issued. This is not a JVM issue. Something is killing your process deliberately. Probably due to running out of memory.